# Adding json object to test.json file in php

Tags: php, json, object, multidimensional-array

I have a json file test.json which has following structure in it

```
{
    "test": {
        "parts": [
             {
                "partgroup": "1",
                "screens": [
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionno": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to add a partgroup inside that parts array my workaround looks like this

```
$data[] = '{
                "partgroup": "2",
                "screens": [
                    {
                        "questions": [
                            {
                                "questionno": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }';
$json = file_get_contents("test.json", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
 foreach($json['test'] as $key=>$value):
     $tempArray = $value['parts'];
 endforeach;
array_push($tempArray, $data);
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
file_put_contents('test.json', $jsonData);
```

here the output is just appending the json at end of the test.json file.
can anyone help me to put the data inside the parts section in the JSON file?

Comment: Decode json, add data, encode json. Never try to do it on your own.

Comment: @aynber i am not getting you